# python best way to insert 60k rows in mysql

Tags: python, mysql

i'm trying to insert 60k rows in mysql but this takes 10 minutes to complete

```
for obj in parsed_objs:
    key = 'randomstring'
    mysqlc.execute("""
        REPLACE INTO infos
            (`key`, `value`)
        VALUES
            (%(key)s, %(value)s)
    """, {'key':key, 'value':obj['val']})
mysqlc.connection.commit()
```

does this is a good way to do this?

when I run commit(), the script runs separated queries or merges all?

Maybe a good idea should be build one unique string like this?

```
insert into table my_table(col1, col2) VALUES (val1_1, val2_1), (val1_2, val2_2);
```

Comment: Have you looked into "LOAD DATA INFILE"?

Comment: yes, this is another option i'll try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible, you'd be better off using the LOAD DATA INFILE... statement in SQL to bulk load data. This will avoid creating a huge number of separate queries to load each row of data.

In the code you've posted, you'll be generating one query per row of data that you want to load. `commit()` just commits the transaction, encompassing all the queries since the transaction was started.

If you do definitely want to do this in Python, you could try using `executemany`, something like this:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="your_host", user="your_user", passwd="your_password", db="your_database")
write_cursor = db.cursor()
write_list = []
for obj in parsed_objs:
  key = 'randomstring'
  write_list.append( (key,obj[key]) )

sql = "REPLACE INTO infos (`key`, `value`) VALUES (%s, %s)"
write_cursor.executemany(sql, write_list)
db.commit()
```

Comment: great! this made 50k inserts in less than 10 seconds. thanks!